# Using WSO2 and OwnUserStore and an own claim

Tags: wso2, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 4.6.0 with an own UserStoreManager. That basically works (mostly) unless I want to read or write an attribute to a user profile. I want to add an additional attribute called token. I created a claim named

```
http://wso2.org/claims/token
```

But, after I added this claim to my SAML provider, I can't login anymore with the following exception:

```
[2014-06-10 00:24:22,635] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.ResponseBuilder} -  Error when reading claim values for generating SAML Response
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getClaimAtrribute(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:778)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2550)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:556)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:550)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.claims.DefaultClaimsRetriever.getUserClaimValues(DefaultClaimsRetriever.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.setClaimsAndValues(SAMLSSOUtil.java:770)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.getAttributes(SAMLSSOUtil.java:747)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.ResponseBuilder.buildSAMLAssertion(ResponseBuilder.java:176)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.process(SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.java:171)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:192)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequestFromLoginPage(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:415)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:246)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:186)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
[2014-06-10 00:24:22,637] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor} -  Error processing the authentication request
org.wso2.carbon.identity.base.IdentityException: Error when reading claim values for generating SAML Response
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.ResponseBuilder.buildSAMLAssertion(ResponseBuilder.java:207)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.ResponseBuilder.buildResponse(ResponseBuilder.java:68)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.processors.SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.process(SPInitSSOAuthnRequestProcessor.java:171)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.SAMLSSOService.authenticate(SAMLSSOService.java:192)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequestFromLoginPage(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:415)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.handleRequest(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:127)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.servlet.SAMLSSOProviderServlet.doPost(SAMLSSOProviderServlet.java:81)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:246)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.sendResponseToCaller(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:223)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.doPost(CommonApplicationAuthenticationServlet.java:186)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:60)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getClaimAtrribute(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:778)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.doGetUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2550)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:556)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getUserClaimValues(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:550)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.claims.DefaultClaimsRetriever.getUserClaimValues(DefaultClaimsRetriever.java:50)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.setClaimsAndValues(SAMLSSOUtil.java:770)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.util.SAMLSSOUtil.getAttributes(SAMLSSOUtil.java:747)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml.builders.ResponseBuilder.buildSAMLAssertion(ResponseBuilder.java:176)
    ... 59 more
```

I get the same exception (without the SAML Response part) when trying to edit my user profile. Apparently I have to do something to force the WSO2 to call methods of my UserStore in order to edit a profile, but I can't find out what yet.
Any hints?

regards
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think  this is an issue with the user store manager that you have written.  As this is a `null pointer`  exception,  you can go through the `778` line in the `AbstractUserStoreManager`  and find out,  why `null` has been generated. I guess, This is due to that,  in your custom user store manager,  you are not initializing the `claimManager`.  Please verify the constructors of your custom class.   You can find the source code of user core from [here](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/kernel/branches/4.2.0/patches/patch0004/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/)